# How to start activity from notification in Android 10?

Tags: android, push-notification

I implement Firebase push notifications, but in notifications, I want to open a specific Activity, it works fine below android 10, and in Android 10 the notification open the app not the desire Actiivity.

My Code in Notifaction is but it don't work in Android 10 or above:

```
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Key", true);
        intent.putExtra("Msg", message);
        // Assign channel ID
        String channel_id = "notification_channel";
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);        // Create a Builder object using NotificationCompat
        // class. This will allow control over all the flags
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder
                = new NotificationCompat
                .Builder(getApplicationContext(),
                channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000,
                        1000, 1000})
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager
                = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Check if the Android Version is greater than Oreo

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel
                    = new NotificationChannel(
                    channel_id, "web_app",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                    notificationChannel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Comment: Please add your code where you are redirecting notification to a particular activity

Comment: Check updated Question

Answer (score 0):

You should set channelid to builder

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel
                    = new NotificationChannel(
                    channel_id, "web_app",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                    notificationChannel);


            //Add this Line
            builder.setChannelId(channel_id);

        }
```

Comment: No, it's doesn't solve my problem, my code work accurately in android 8, but for Android 10 it instead of opening desire activity, open launcher activity and also data was not send throgh intent

Comment: @hus98ain from where you sending notification web server or  app itself and post that code also.

Comment: I use firebase push notifications (Cloud Messaging)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an action eg: "com.app.action.notification" to Intent and Activity (AndroidManifest.xml) like this:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction("com.app.action.notification");
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);        // Create a Builder object using NotificationCompat
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.app.action.notification" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `PendingIntent.getActivity` like below.

```
    val notificationIntent: Intent
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, msgData.channel)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_rss_feed)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationDescription)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_EVENT)
                .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1_000L, 1_000L, 1_000L, 1_000L, 1_000L))
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

        // Required in Android 12
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            flags = flags or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

     notificationIntent = Intent(this, YourActivity::class.java).apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_MAIN
                setClass(this@YourService, YourActivity::class.java)
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) // Starting Android 9 calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag
            }

            // Open app Activity via getActivity
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, notificationID,
                notificationIntent, flags or PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
            )

            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent) // Clicking this notification will launch the activity specified in the Intent
```

Also note that you can no longer start activity with BroadcastReceiver or which they call trampoline in Android 12 and above.

Answer (score -1):

Not enough information to give a detailed answer. Please provide some code.
Meanwhile, you can check default approach which works like a charm with Android 10: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation

Comment: This method not work in Android 10 or above